# Use MongoDb with Symfony

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I am new in mongodb.I have Succesfully installed mongodb.Now I want to Connect mongodb with symfony.

When I install these:

```
 "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
```

I got error like:

```
Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA6 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.0.0-beta1,<1.1-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA7 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA8 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA9 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA10 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.2.0].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA11 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.2.0].
```

Comment: what was the `composer` command that you ran?

Comment: sudo php composer.phar update

Answer (score 0):

I Solved My problem.

Simply add  extension=mongo.so in the php.ini file here etc/php5/cli.